# Key analysis of piece with roots in A and later on G

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions, analysis, key-signatures

So I have a piece written in C, with very few accidentals. However the bass resides mainly on A. Am I correct in assuming that **most probably** it means the piece is actually in A minor?

Later on I use a Ab and Eb to modulate the bass to G, am I again correct in assuming that section is **probably** in G minor, since G major doesn't feature B flat and E flat, but G minor does?

Of course a more extensive analysis would be necessary to know for sure, but I'm just trying to verify whether my hunch reasoning is correct.

Comment: IMO _**keys**_ per-se are highly overrated, particularly in modern music - in depth analysis of the key is usually an academic exercise more than anything else. IMO time is better spent on improving the music than analyzing the key. The music is what it is: Use you ear and play/write the appropriate notes based on the chords and melody. If and when you need to notate, just use the key signature that makes it easiest to read.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But having _some_ sense of where you are keywise is useful I think

Comment: I think the music tells your ear how the music works. You can have a 32 bar jazz piece that might technically be in 4 or 8 different keys but there is a logical progression that tells you what to play even if you never bother analyzing what keys you're working with. Maybe it depends on the instrument in question. I play bass and mostly jazz - I'll just think to myself 'this thing is a series of II/V/I's progressing, over a Dm triad," I know the chords and how they work together -_key_ is irrelevant to me.

Comment: Hehe well, I can't even tell _that_ ...

Comment: _I can't even tell that_ - maybe because you're focusing too much on formal keys and not learning proper analysis of the music itself? Just thinking out loud. I know that for a number of years, before I learned a decent amount of theory, I thought a  lot about **keys** because they were my only theoretical anchor.  Now the more I know, the less important **key** becomes -look at a chart and analyze it for what it is. Only if I have to play a discreet notated melody, I'll look at the key signature so I can read the notes properly. My teacher, a working jazz pro, mostly agrees with me.

Comment: Actually, before yesterday I had no real idea what key meant. So I was just trying to verify what I read yesterday. Heh, 4 weeks ago I thought the flags were visual embellishments. I.e. I'm an absolute beginner. Hm, time to put on some Bowie!

Comment: @Stinkfoot - have to disagree to a great extent with importance of **keys**. Playing a lot with and without dots/charts (which I do)  means several things. Without means that knowing which key a piece is in helps me to navigate. I know a start point, and probably an end point. I know which harmonies to expect, and when a mod. appears, it's usually no surprise, and I have clues as to where we're going. With dots/charts, the first thing I see is a key sig. Relevant in that it again gives me a clue as to what to expect.   Not having the key is somewhat like having a map but no compass...

Comment: ...or vice versa. It gives a good start point, and clues to directions taken after. Take a simple example of a written piece , ostensibly in C/Am, but with loads of 'accidentals' throughout. No real clues. Would you, at some point, be thinking, well, all those # could have been put at the beginning, showing it's in B major, and saved a lot of unnecessary fuss?  Locking into a key is most likely a simple way for most players to get into a piece, and certainly is good for any listener, who will probably feel a 'key' during the piece being played.

Comment: @Tim I think it depends on the genre, the instrument you're playing and your role in the music. If I go to play bass on 32 bar jazz piece that modulates every 4 bars, if don't have to sight read (which I cannot do very well at all) the key/key signature aren't going to help me much. I would just try to play through the changes with root/5 a few times until I understood the structure and had it under my fingers. I would never think about the key - just about how the chords relate to one another so I could play through them and do something interesting.

Comment: @Tim - And I believe that it happens often enough that people get bogged down in pedantics when it comes to formally defining a "key" in situations where it is ambiguous and not particularly relevant - analysis of the relationships between the notes and chords will be more fruitful. I've played (and learned from) so very good musicians and when I use to ask what key (I no longer do) the answer would be "not sure - you could say D or maybe A.. or maybe it's G.. - just play the changes and work them."

Comment: @Stinkfoot - we're probably agreeing from different angles. A piece such as you describe, I would compartmentalise it into 4/8 bar key changes, and tackle each part as being in that particular 'key'. Bearing in mind that a lot of mods/changes  are to related 'keys', you seem to be doing the same thing, but from a slightly different standpoint.  And, yes, the relationships between chords is often key based. But thinking G>C is I>IV in one key, but V>I in another doesn't really help me in my playing, as a simple example.  it's not so much pedantics as knowing where I am, and where I need to go.

Comment: @Tim _and tackle each part as being in that particular 'key'_ - I can agree with that. You know that for these 8 bars you're working through Bbm, etc. But I gather the question is dealing with something different, which is why I commented.

Answer (score 1):

In the first part, if it is in A minor, there *could* be some G# notes - the leading note in A minor. Another good guide is to stop where a phrase sounds it will stop naturally, and play a C major, then repeat with A minor. Which sounds better? If that G# is present just before that point, it'll most likely be Am.

On the Bb/Gm part, again, leading note of F# may appear, hinting at Gm.

Having said that, the minor keys don't always have the 'sharpened leading note', so there doesn't have to be G# in Am, or F# in Gm.

Comment: In the first part, the only accidentals I have are D#/Eb, G#/Ab. And in the second part D#/Eb. No F# at all. (Ah, just realised I have a typo in my question: Bb should be Ab)

Comment: So, follow-up question, would it then be best to use G# (instead of Ab) in the first part? What about D#/Eb?

Comment: In the first part, you probably have some A notes already, so Ab isn't the best to call it, as maybe you have no G notes, only G#?

Comment: I have many A's _and_ G's in both parts :)

Comment: At this rate, we'll need to listen to and/or view the sheet music of this piece to know for sure.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - what will be gained from "knowing for sure"? Will it improve the music? Very unlikely. Notation? Just use the key signature that makes it easiest  to read.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - which is one of the things the OP is trying to establish...

Comment: @Tim - from here, maybe that's the point. it's not in the question IMO.

Comment: @Creynders - is your question actually about notation? What key signature to use when you write it out?  I am almost entirely involved in jazz so I don't think in those terms  - more along the lines of what I mentioned above. Maybe I am just mixing you up. Perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - the OP does seem, from where I am, to be talking about key centres, which presumably relates to key sigs. And are you saying that keys don't exist in jazz?! Every jazz piece I play - not avant-garde or more modern than maybe '80s stuff, granted, has a key sig. It makes life easier for the other players, too.

Comment: @Stinkfoot as I wrote, I'm just trying to figure out if I really understood what I'd been reading about chords and keys. I have a piece in C, but I noticed the bass is mainly on A; did I understand the theory correctly when I assume that part's probably in A minor, since 1/ it's the relative of C minor 2/ there's few accidentals. Nothing more. But maybe it's such a noob reasoning that it's hard for you to imagine... :)

Comment: @Tim _And are you saying that keys don't exist in jazz_ - Of course not. All I'm saying is that looking at a piece in its entirety and trying to affirm that it's in one particular key using standard rules of analysis often doesn't work very well or mean very much, unless you're writing a "jazz composition". Take a tune like _Silver's Serenade_  or maybe _Blue Bossa_:  In one particular key? Modulating?   You know the chords and their scales and the structure of the piece - that's what you need to play it-also  many rock songs. Formal analysis of a dubious "key" doesn't add anything, IMO.

Comment: @Creynders _maybe it's such a noob reasoning that it's hard for you to imagine_ - certainly not. I don't know much at all - I just ignore a lot of things that aren't relevant to what/how I play. :) See my comment above to Tim "And are you saying..." - Your question seems to be fine and it's very important if you need to notate it for an ensemble etc. My point is simply that there are a many musical situations,  especially in jazz,  where the clear determination of one particular "key" isn't really important. A piece might have 8 "keys", or no key at all-just some chords or scales that work.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - played Blue Bossa a few times - last month in 5/4. It's an almost standard 12 bar, in one key. We must agree to differ on the importance (or not) of establishing keys!

Comment: @Tim - you must be talking about a different Blue Bossa! I'm talking about Kenny Dorham's: http://www.jazzguitar.be/backing-tracks/blue-bossa.html - it's a 16 bar tune with modulation: _Blue Bossa is in the key of C minor.
On bars 1 to 8 and 13 to 16 use the C minor scale (C Aeolian) or C blues scale On the G7 alt you can play a C harmonic minor scale or a G altered scale. There's a modulation to Db major on bar 9 that lasts until bar 12. It's a regular II V I, you can play the Db major scale there._ How  does the key signature help me here? IMO it doesn't.

Comment: @Tim - it's really a minor point when you get down to it. As you said, when you play something like that, you are using "keys", although not in the traditional sense, but piecemeal. It's a question of terminology mostly - I just think of it in terms of chords and scales - "OK - this is 8 bars in Cm... etc"  because "key" to me means the key signature on the staff

Comment: @Stinkfoot - slight glitch ! Getting mixed up with 'All Blues'. Haven't played Blue Bossa for a couple of years. Will regurgitate it and come back. Just off to play now!

Comment: @Tim - Easy mistake. A lot of different _Kinds of Blue_ out there... **Blue Bossa** is ubiquitous in NYC cocktail lounges. At any rate it's just a question of of terminology here - in piece like that I'll just think "OK this starts with 8 bars playing playing through a Cm scale..." etc - etc. That is how I navigate through most jazz things (I play mostly hard bop and 'soul jazz'.) But if it's straight RnB or blues tune, then yes, I will just think in terms of a "key" - 'this is a 12 bar in E with a quick change and a simple I/V turnaround". etc